# Add variable value in single quoted string. Expand variable within single quotes

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have tried different variations of the below commands but non work.
I simply want to run the following command using a variable within the location string:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE data OWNER appuser
  LOCATION '/var/lib/pgsql95/:variable/pg_tblspc/data';
```

What has been tried (variations):

```
EXECUTE CREATE TABLESPACE data OWNER appuser
  LOCATION ''/var/lib/pgsql95/' || base || '/pg_tblspc/data'';';
```

and

```
PREPARE tablespace (text) AS
  CREATE TABLESPACE aspire_data OWNER aspireapp
  LOCATION '/var/lib/pgsql95/$1/pg_tblspc';

EXECUTE tablespace('base');
```

and

```
\set myvariable 'base'
CREATE TABLESPACE aspire_data OWNER aspireapp
  LOCATION '/var/lib/pgsql95/':myvariable'/pg_tblspc';
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- This will concatenate the values:
\set myvariable '/var/lib/pgsql95/' :myvariable '/pg_tblspc'

-- This will expand the variable single-quoted:
CREATE TABLESPACE aspire_data OWNER aspireapp LOCATION :'myvariable'
```

Comment: I like this, can define the entire string (in my case the comment for a table description) at the top of a psql script.

Comment: Does the string concatenation only work in \set or can you use it also inside statements like ' CREATE... LOCATION '/var/' :mydir '/files'`

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution:

```
-- Single quote is escaped and concatenated to the front and end of string
\set myvariable '''' /var/lib/pgsql95/:variable/pg_tblspc/data ''''

CREATE TABLESPACE aspire_data OWNER aspireapp LOCATION :myvariable
```

Peter's solution (and mine) may not work depending on your psql client version.

[See SQL Interpolation section in the PostgreSQL documentation for your psql client version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION)

If nothing works, and you are able to just pass in the variable from the command line with single quotes already around it, that may work too.